# How can I change my block of code that was using the file() function to now use the open() function

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to loop through `feedlist.txt`, I understand that `file()` and `open()` are used the same. I am attempting to do exercises from an older ML book.

```
apcount={}
wordcounts={}
for feedurl in file('feedlist.txt'):
    title,wc=getwordcounts(feedurl)
    wordcounts[title]=wc
    for word,count in wc.items():
        apcount.setdefault(word,0)
        if count>1:
            apcount[word]+=1
```

Comment: If you know they're the same, how do you have a question at all?

Comment: (Also, `file()` is still as valid as if it ever was, so if you're surmising that you're having a problem due to syntax becoming outdated, that's probably an inaccurate guess, so a question about the **real** problem you're having, not about your guess as to its cause, is likely to be appropriate).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `file` is gone in Python 3, so no, not valid in modern Python.

Comment: Ahh, so Python **3**. That should really be included in the tagging.

Comment: I'm still unclear on how the OP has a question, though. If they know they're the same, I *assume* they've already tried like-for-like replacement. If that doesn't work, perhaps they should be including the way it fails in the question?

Comment: The error i recieved was, NameError: name 'file' is not defined. I searched some posts and got the impression file() was no longer used in python3 and

Comment: yes i should have mentioned python3

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
with open('feedlist.txt','r') as fp:
    filecontent = fp.readlines()
    title,wc = getwordcounts(filecontent)
    wordcounts[title]=wc
    for word,count in wc.items():
        apcount.setdefault(word,0)
        if count>1:
            apcount[word]+=1
```

`with` handles the file exceptions and the commands after `with` are executed only if the file exists.

Comment: thank you very much, that got me past my error, much appreciated. now having a filenotfound error hah. thanks for the help v.coder

Comment: im getting fileNotFoundError which is weird because the file seemed to have saved fine( i used wget) but I've gotten past the nameError which is nice. any thoughts?

Comment: Is the path to the file correct? Can you check filename and directory in which it is present.

Comment: I found the directory the file is present in and added it to the file name;        with open('E.J/feedlist.txt','r') as fp: I am getting a no such file or directory error (I apologize about my formatting)

Answer (score 0):

To loop through each line, as you do in the original, here is the equivalent using `open`.  This will close the file after leaving the `with` block.  As in the original, a single line at a time is passed to `getwordcounts()`.

```
with open('feedlist.txt') as f:
    for feedurl in f:
        title,wc=getwordcounts(feedurl)
        wordcounts[title]=wc
        for word,count in wc.items():
            apcount.setdefault(word,0)
            if count>1:
                apcount[word]+=1
```

Comment: Does this add anything [to the answer by v.coder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46721286/14122) that preceded it by 5 minutes?

Comment: thank you charles duffy, ill be more clear in future posts

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This example passes a single line at a time to `getwordcounts()`, as in the original, instead of using `readlines()` and passing a list to `getwordcounts()`

Comment: Having that explanation in the answer rather than the comments would strengthen it.